# How do I resolve the Transporter error "The provisioning profile included in the bundle is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]"?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I have successfully built, signed, and archived my app! However, when I try to send it to App Store Connect (I've tried using Transporter and Fastlane), I get this error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.myapp [Payload/My App.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."
```

I am indeed using a distribution provisioning profile, and I have the codesigning certificate on the machines doing the building. I've tried deleting both from all machines, then re-downloading them from Apple Developer, but that doesn't seem to have fixed the issue.

I've also tried deleting and re-creating the provisioning profiles, but that didn't seem to affect this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've discovered this was a forced Bitrise configuration change I was unaware of, which was [quietly announced on their forum](https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/xcode-archive-export-for-ios-v4-0-0/18323#breaking-changes-and-migration-guide-1).

tl;dr Bitrise changed their `xcodebuild` step's configuration so that `ExportMethod` was set to `development`, whereas this needed it to be set to `app-store`. I had previously manually set it to `app-store`, but during an upgrade, the upgrade process unset that back to `development`. Setting that back to `app-store` fixed my issue.